# Handling piped io in Lua

Tags: io, lua, pipe, stdin

I have searched a lot for this but can't find answers anywhere. I am trying to do something like the following:

`cat somefile.txt | grep somepattern | ./script.lua`

I haven't found a single resource on handling piped io in Lua, and can't figure out how to do it. Is there a good way, non hackish way to do tackle it? Preferably buffered for lower memory usage, but I'll settle for reading the whole file at once if thats the only alternative.

It would be really disappointing to have to write it into a temp file and then load it into the program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard lirary has an `io.stdin` and an `io.stdout` that you can use for input and output without havig to resort to temporary files. You can also use `io.read` isntead of `someFile:read` and it will read from stdin by default.

http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html

The buffering is responsibility of the operating system that is providing the pipes. You don't need to worry too much about it when writing your programs.

---

edit: Apparently when you mentioned buffering you were thinking about reading part of the file as opposed to loading the whole file into a string. `io.read` can take a numeric parameter to read up to a certain number of bytes from input, returning `nil` if no characters could be read.

```
local size = 2^13      -- good buffer size (8K)
while true do
  local block = io.read(size)
  if not block then break end
  io.write(block)
end
```

Comment: That last chunk of the page is what settled for me, would be cool for you to include that example in your answer. That is exactly what I meant by buffering. The equivalent of reading n bytes from stdin into an array, instead of pulling the whole file at once into memory in C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another (simpler) alternative is the io.lines() iterator but without a filename inside the parentheses.  Example:

```
for line in io.lines() do
  print(line)
end
```

UPDATE: To get a number of characters you can write a wrapper around this.  Example:

```
function io.chars(n,filename)
  n = n or 1                  --default number of characters to read at a time
  local chars = ''
  local wrap, yield = coroutine.wrap, coroutine.yield
  return wrap(function()
                for line in io.lines(filename) do
                  line = chars .. line .. '\n'
                  while #line >= n do
                    yield(line:sub(1,n))
                    line = line:sub(n+1)
                  end
                  chars = line
                end
                if chars ~= '' then yield(chars) end
              end)
end

for text in io.chars(30) do
  io.write(text)
end
```

Comment: Reminds me of Python, thanks for the tip! Is there a way for it to instead of reading a line, reading `n` chars?